# .bin file generated by word2vec is not readable

Tags: word2vec

I am new to word2vec.I have run word2vec code in python given a corpus to train.Model is saved in .bin file extension.But it is not readable,like below

:�Z�;5>|:#�պSK������A���<�?;X�;���;�]��ʋy��#ع�#G;�##���)���#;c�:��}�:�2�;����2#�;>�i�##n;p+�;�#�:P�ّ:�u,���#�?�#���W��#�93�����T�i##;d�Q;��
;��F;#�N;:9�;��к[q0;C�ƹv�";�ܚ��#U�#�I���7���պ+�#��T�;KC�7Y#��#�#�{��A4����:ܟ��b�#;'�#�##�;W-��$p�  �v�"��;�3u;k�;ꌒ�?�F��� �

Comment: Can someone help me Whats the matter with bin file?

Comment: Are you using `gensim`. If yes you can save using save_word2vec_format(). In that give the parameter `binary=False`.

Comment: Thank you so much..I got it

Answer (score 0):

That is, in fact, the way a 'binary=True`-saved file will and should look: with lots of raw binary numerical (floating-point) data that looks like garbage if interpreted as text. Other code that reads that format will work with it fine.

However, if you want something that's easier on *your* eyes, save using the `binary=False` optional parameter. You may also want to use a different file-extension (such as `.txt`) to hint to others (and your future-self) that the file isn't raw binary data.

Comment: Thank you.And one thing more.I have to understand word2vec skip gram code available at github as part of my research.I have basic understanding of word2vec like,the way one-hot encoded vector is presented to the input layer and then initialized with random weights in hidden layer and finally appying softmax at the output layer,but the problem is that I am not understanding the code.Where the one hot encoded vector is presented to the input layer and where weights are randomly initialized and all that?.Can you suggest me something?.Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: There is more than one implementation of word2vec "at github", but I'll guess you still mean gensim. Everything is in the source code at <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py> (though in practice a proper install will replace some of those functions with those in the Cython file <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx>, for 100x faster execution). SG mode essentially "looks up" the projection inputs when filling `l1` in `train_sg_pair()` . Random init happens in `reset_weights()`.